# Arrays in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, arrays

In declaring an array in VB, would you ever leave the zero element empty and adjust the code to make it more user friendly?

This is for Visual Basic 2008

Comment: Only if you hate every other developer on your team.

Comment: Since `DIM x(12)` yields an array with elements 0-12, it's not uncommon to do so.

Comment: Hmm, are we talking about VB.NET or VB 6 here?

Comment: Visual Basic 2008 is Visual Basic .NET. The 2008 refers to the version of Visual Studio that you're using to write the code, not the language itself. VB.NET is the current version, and has been for years. But it was a very dramatic departure from the previous VB language (version 6, back in 1998), so that does affect how we answer the question. I know it's confusing; thanks for clarifying your question.

Comment: @Gabe so, you're telling me that, in VB (which one?) when you ask the compiler for an array with twelve slots it gives you one with thirteen?

Comment: @Will: No, I'm saying that in the `DIM` statement, you are specifying the *bounds* of the array, not the number of elements. `DIM x(12)` is the same as `DIM x(0 to 12)`, meaning that the lowest element index is 0 and the highest index is 12, for a total of 13 elements. And I'm pretty sure that all versions of VB act like this, though some may have defaulted to 1 as the lower bound.

Comment: @gabe I threw up a little in my mouth.

Comment: @Will: It's for backwards-compatibility reasons. VB 6 used to allow you to specify any lower bound that you want. You could say `Dim x(5 to 11)` if you wanted, and get an array with 7 elements. Non-standard, perhaps, but certainly convenient and more flexible. VB.NET retained the same syntax, while limiting arrays to a fixed lower bound of zero. There's no particular reason why the syntax in C# is "better", other than it's consistent with C and C++ (obviously by design).

Comment: @CodyGray: Eh, dunno.  Seems to me setting the bottom index of an array to an arbitrary index is a maintenance nightmare in the making.

Comment: VB6 varies on whether arrays are 0 indexed or 1 indexed, depending on what you are doing.  It supports user choice of indexing, and in fact the included classes vary in whether they start at 1 or 0.

Comment: Your first comment made me chuckle will. =) To the OP - use the language as it's intended. Adjust to it instead of taking a shortcut to make it like something else.

Comment: Old post - but I thought you might enjoy the historical reason why this had be a possible option in VB6, and it might clarify what the true reason for ever considering this :)
In the original BASIC language (born 1965), array indexes started at 1. Hence throughout the history of Basic variations there has been a desire to allow code to be ported and programmers to feel comfortable...

Comment: ....  and this was because BASIC was intended as novice/learner programming language and it was felt to be more natural to start an array at 1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No, I wouldn't do that.** It *seems* like it might help maintainability, but that's a very short-sighted view.

Think about it this way. It only takes each programmer who has to understand and maintain the code a short amount of time to get comfortable with zero-indexed arrays. But if you're using one-based arrays, which are unlike those found in almost all other VB.NET code, and in fact almost every other common programming language, it will take everyone on the team  much longer. They'll be constantly making mistakes, tripping up because their natural assumptions aren't accurate in this *one special case*.

I know how it feels. When I worked in VB 6, I loved one-based arrays. They were very natural for the type of data that I was storing, and I used them all over the place. Perfectly documentable here, because you have an explicit syntax to specify the upper *and lower* bounds of the array. That's not the case in VB.NET (which is a newer, but *incompatible* version of the Visual Basic language), where all arrays have to be zero-indexed. I had a hard time switching to VB.NET's zero-based arrays for the first couple of days. After that initial period of adjustment, I can honestly say I've never looked back.

Some might argue that leaving the first element of every array empty would consume extra memory needlessly. While that's obviously true, I think it's a secondary reason behind the one I presented above. Good developers write code for others to read, so I commend you for considering how to make your code logical and understandable. You're on the right path by asking this question. But in the long run, I don't think this decision is a good one.

There might be a handful of exceptions in *very specific cases*, depending on the type of data that you're storing in the array. But again, failing to do this across the board seems like it would *hurt* readability in the aggregate, rather than helping it. It's not particularly counter-intuitive to simply write the following, once you've learned how arrays are indexed:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To (myArray.Length - 1)
    'Do work
Next
```

And remember that in VB.NET, you can also use the `For Each` statement to iterate through your array elements, which many people find more readable. For example:

```
 For Each i As Integer In myArray
     'Do work
 Next
```

Answer (score 3):

First, it is about programmer friendly, not user friendly. User will never know the code is 0-based or 1-based.

Second, 0-based is the default and will be used more and more.

Third, 0-based is more natural to computer. From the very element, it has two status, 0 and 1, not 1 and 2.

I have upgraded a couple of VB6 projects to vb.net. To modify to 0-based array in the beginning is better than to debug the code a later time.

Comment: It certainly seems reasonable to assume that by "user", he meant the next programmer who has to maintain the code. That is really the "user" of a program's source code, after all. And as indicated in my answer, an important concern and one worth commending the asker for paying attention to. Also, there's no particular reason why zero-based arrays are "more natural" to the computer. I don't understand what array indexing has to do with the state of binary flags. What if you had an array with 3 elements? I also don't agree that code should be written to increase the comfort of the *computer*.

Comment: Ok, why it is "more natural" to the computer? If you have a computer that has only 4 digits, (or 64 digits, the same), then you can have the minimum of 0000 and the maximum 1111, which is from 0 to 15, not 1 to 16. Yes, it doesn't have to be the way for Array to a "user", the programmer. But if the programmer knows that the Array actually has an address (pointer), and it is the address of the first element of the Array, and the next (second) is at the (address + 1), then we know that array is 0-based in nature.

Answer (score 2):

- Most of my VB.Net arrays are 0-based and every element is used. That's usual in VB.Net and code [mustn't *surprise* the reader](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment). Readability is vital.
- Any exceptions? Maybe if I had a program ported from VB6, so it used 0-based arrays with unused initial elements, and it needed a *small* change, I might match the pattern of the existing code. [Least surprise again](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrincipleOfLeastAstonishment).
- 99 times out of 100 the question shouldn't arise because you should be using `List(Of T)` rather than an array!

Comment: Agreed on the suggestion to use generic collections instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Who are the "users" that are going to see the array indexes? Any good developer will be able to handle a zero-indexed array and no real user should ever see them. If the user has to interact with the array, then make an actually user-friendly system for doing so (text or a 1-based virtual index or whatever is called for).

Answer (score 0):

In visual basic is it possible to declare an array starting from 1, if you find inconvenient to use a 0 based array.

```
Dim array(1 to 10) as Integer
```

It is just a matter of tastes. I use 1 based arrays in visual basic but 0 based arrays in C ;)

Comment: Note that this is *only* possible in VB 6. At the time this answer was written, the question was vague on which version of VB was in use. But in light of the more recent clarifications, this code *will not work* in VB.NET. All arrays must be zero-indexed.

Comment: In Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0, you can define arrays with the lower bounds and upper bounds set to any integer. In Microsoft Visual Basic .NET, the lower bound of every array dimension is zero (0). You cannot declare the lower bound for arrays with any other integer. In addition, the Option Base statement is not supported in Visual Basic .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Zero based arrays are an unnatural way to think of ordinal lists.  If you have a list of 5 items, you would think of the first item as item 1, not item 0.

This seemingly harmless change to zero in the programming world is not harmless at all.  It makes the user displayed ordinal number one higher than the array number used to store the data.

Millions of programmers bought into this but in my opinion it is less friendly to code with this difference than it would be to begin arrays at one.

Then an ordered list item's ordinal number would always match its array position number.

The 0 start was an easy way to make more elegant loop references etc. because we generally initialize to to zero and a value of the ubound plays nice with lower level loop constructs if it's zero based.  The romans would call that crazy.

Don't bother responding, I know why it's done, I simply don't happen to agree with a zero based array.

Comment: Your answer is opinion based and adds no more information to the question. Try [edit] your answer to a shorter, not opinion based one.

Comment: Lists, read by humans, of which programmers are a subset, almost always begin with 1.  Zero-based lists are an extra mental step for all people, even the ones who are okay with zero based arrays.  I don't recommend changing any code bases to change something so ingrained into todays code.  I was, however, pointing out that concepts that gain traction are not always the best methods for human processing.  You don't like my answer?  That's fine, but it does add value as written.

Comment: "In know why it's done." -- I don't think you do. It's not the creators of programming languages that came up with this. It's how indexed access works *on the machine level*. The index is added to the base address. This gave birth to e.g. `a[x]`, `*(a + x)` and `*(x + a)` meaning the same thing in C. A 1-based array would need additional logic, because on the machine level you *must* use 0-based indexing (or waste time, memory, and / or logic gates).