# Selecting specific text from a textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I had this select query where textbox value is my parameter.

The case is, when I type text in the textbox it will be the reference for my select query. For example below,

Suppose my textbox has already a content;

```
123 32 5
```

And then i will add some text for my select query

```
123 32 5 66
```

The return value will be "66". And if i add another text

```
123 32 55 66 6952
```

The return value will be "6952". And So on, regardless of the length of the text

My idea here is that I start selecting the values from the first space to the right of the textbox. But I have no idea on how to do it.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: If you have no idea how to manipulate a `String` in VB.NET then you should do some research on how to manipulate `Strings` in VB.NET.  SO is not an alternative to doing your own research. It's where you come when you've done your research, tried to put what you found to use and what you think is correct doesn't work. You then post what you've done and an explanation of how it doesn't meet your expectations. We're here to help with specific issues, not to teach you how to write code. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yeah right! i'm just new with programming you know! That is why we're here, to help somebody. perhaps you should also share your idea with this issue for somebody to start with instead of bluh! bluh! bluh!.. you're not helping. If you want to help, just share a little bit of your idea! @jmcilhinney

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450519/arrays-in-visual-basic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer to your question. Now if you have a question related to your code then you should post some code to go with it showing you have done a bit of work. I'll give you a hint. Strings.Split()

This gives the same result....the last item in your split

```
Dim xx As String = "438 2374 8437 46327"
Dim xstr As String = xx.Split(" ").Last

Dim xxstr() As String = xx.Split(" ")
MsgBox(xstr)
MsgBox(xxstr(xxstr.Count - 1))
```

[Play with strings!](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Helo @chillzy.. I found an idea on how to get value of a first text in a textbox using that "Strings.Split" you provided. but the problem is, i cannot get the last value of that textbox.Here was the code `Dim TextboxValue As String = txtScheduleID.Text` `Dim vals = TextboxValue.Split(" ").Last()`